# Power Supply For my future build

Tags: pc, power-supply

I am currently under the dilemma of choosing the right PSU for this build:

- CPU: [Intel Skylake, Core i5 6600K 3.5GHz](http://ark.intel.com/products/88191/Intel-Core-i5-6600K-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz)
- RAM: HyperX Fury Black 8GB DDR4 2133MHz CL14 Dual Channel Kit
- Motherboard: [MSI H170A PC Mate](http://www.msi.com/product/motherboard/H170A-PC-MATE.html)
- Some SSD + HDD, not sure at the moment how much (irrelevant)
- Water cooling for the CPU (have not decided yet).

My budget is around $120-$130.

I must note that I will also get a GPU in the future, and I want the PSU to work *with upgrades*, instead of replacing it.

*Also I have to ask this:*
What is with the bronze/gold/platinum labels on the PSUs?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the [Antec High Current Gamer HCG-750M](http://www.superbiiz.com/detail.php?name=PS-HCG750M), a 750W, semi modular, 80+ Bronze PSU made by Seasonic. This will support any single GPU system and most dual GPU systems, with some light overclocking (up to GTX 980 or R9 380), though two of the higher end AMD GPUs will require additional capacity. The power supply is the [same platform as the M2II Evo](http://www.jonnyguru.com/modules.php?name=NDReviews&op=Story7&reid=357), a very high quality PSU.

80+ certification measures the efficiency of the PSU. Silver and Gold PSUs are a few percent more efficent that Bronze PSUs, which are at least 82-85% efficent, depending on load.